# How to deserialize a child list of interfaces?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-2, serialization, json.net

I'm using ASP.NET MVC2 and I have the following object structure:

```
public class IDealer {
  string Name { get; set; }
  List<IVehicle> Vehicles { get; set; }
}

public class DealerImpl {
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public List<IVehicle> Vehicles { get; set; }
}

public interface IVehicle {
    string Type { get; }
}

public class Car : IVehicle {
    public string Type { get { return this.GetType().FullName; } }
}

public class Truck : IVehicle {
    public string Type { get { return this.GetType().FullName; } }
}
```

I have the following class as my ModelBinder which deserializes objects in my page requests:

```
public class JsonModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder {
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) {
        return deserialize(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }

    protected static bool IsJSONRequest(ControllerContext controllerContext) {
        var contentType = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.ContentType;
        return contentType.Contains("application/json");
    }

    protected virtual object deserialize(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) {
        Type modelType = bindingContext.ModelMetadata.ModelType;

        bool isNotConcrete = bindingContext.ModelMetadata.ModelType.IsInterface || bindingContext.ModelMetadata.ModelType.IsAbstract;
        if (!IsJSONRequest(controllerContext)) {
            return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
        } else {
            var request = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request;
            var jsonStringData = new StreamReader(request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
            if (isNotConcrete) {
                Dictionary<string, Object> result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Object>>(jsonStringData);
                string type = result["Type"] as string;
                modelType = Type.GetType(type + ",MyCompany.Common");
            }

            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonStringData, modelType, new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto });
        }       
    }
}

// ASP.NET MVC Controller
protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext) {
  base.Initialize(requestContext);
  ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new JsonModelBinder();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult addUpdateDealer(IDealer dealer) {
  // breaks before here with the error in the comment below
}

// and in the aspx page
<script>
var model = <%= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model, Formatting.None, new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto }) %>;
</script>
```

The problem I'm running into, is that when the code tries to deserialize the child list of IVehicles, it does not know which type of vehicle to instantiate.  I put a property on IVehicle called "Type" which could be used to help determine which class to instantiate, but I'm not sure what/where/how to provide an override to perform this check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is similar to what JSON.NET has built-in now, called TypeNameHandling. [Here are the release notes on that](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2010/08/13/json-net-3-5-release-8-3-5-final.aspx).

Your JSON message will need to include a `$type` property, which won't be deserialized, but will be interpreted by the deserializer as the concrete type to use.

Comment: This seems like the right direction, but given my example above, how can I automatically get the $type property into my IVehicle implementations?

Comment: When creating the JSON message to begin with? `var jsonString = JsonConvert.Serialize(myObject, new JsonSerializerSettings{TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto});`

Comment: Ok so this definitely is getting written out to the child objects.  Is there a way to do this if the dealer class is also an interface? i changed the original code to show the example. It correctly put the $type into the child list, but not onto the dealer itself, even though it is an interface.

Comment: Hmm, yeah that makes sense since `Auto` works by comparing the requested type to the actual type, and since Dealer is the top-most node there's nothing to compare. One option is to just use `TypeNameHandling.All`, which means it will always emit `$type`.

Comment: I see what that added, it's a lot, but that's ok.  I'll put my ASP.NET controller method in my original post, but I unfortunately get the following error: The parameters dictionary contains an invalid entry for parameter 'dealer' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult addUpdateDealer(MyCompany.Common.Model.Dealer.IDealer)' in 'MyCompany.Common.Web.Controllers.DealerController'. The dictionary contains a value of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject', but the parameter requires a value of type 'MyCompany.Common.Model.Dealer.IDealer'

Comment: Ok I figured it out.  Editing the original post with the working answer.  Thanks a million!